# copy all *.mkv in subdirectories to parent directory

Tags: linux, files, copying

Roughly, I have a folder setup like this on a linux server:

```
/show/season01/show01/shows01e01.mkv
/show/season02/show01/shows02e01.mkv
/show/season03/show01/shows03e01.mkv
```

I want to eliminate the folders.... I want to copy the `*.mkv` files to the `/show/` directory...

Can someone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex's answer is fine.  Here's a couple of alternate ways to do it too:

1. find + xargs:

   `find /show -name "*.mkv" -print0 | xargs -0 -Imkv cp mkv /show/`
2. find + parallel:

   `find /show -name "*.mkv" -print0 | parallel -0 -j+0 cp {} /show/`

the only interesting thing about using [parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) instead of `find/exec` is that it can execute multiple commands in parallel.  The `-j+0` arguments will make it launch as many jobs at once as there are cpu cores.  That might not be particularly useful if this operation is completemy disk-bound, but potentially it could speed up copying large numbers of files.

Comment: Are you missing a closing quote or is the one that's there extraneous?

Answer (score 3):

`find /show -name "*.mkv" -exec cp {} /show/ \;` will do the trick

Comment: I cant edit because its a 1 letter change, but *always* put the trailing `/` on directories. So `... cp {} /show/ ...`. If `/show` doesnt exist, the files will all clobber eachother on copy rather than generating errors

Comment: "-exec mv" has more sense.

Comment: You are right guys. Edited a command to add a trailing slash. Yep, `mv` has more sense, but the task was to copy files for some reason.